# How can I calculate the area inside non contiguous shapes in an image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have an interesting series of images of cell growth and My company is trying to quantify programmatically how much of the dish contains cells and how much doesn't.

I've included an image below as an example of I have. Any enclosed area is cell growth while any other non-black area is not.

I've tried a few different filters and a floodfill algorithm to search between regions of cell growth, but having little experience in image processing haven't had much success. Here's some code I put together from the internet to count the number of black pixels. However, it's so slow I think it's better to ask y'all.

```
image = Image.open("Images/24Hour/HB15_2.jpg")
image = image.getdata()

def is_black_enough(pixel):
    r, g, b = pixel
    return r < 10 and g < 10 and b < 10
w, h = np.asarray(image).shape
black_pixels = 0
for pixel in image:
    if is_black_enough(pixel)==True:
        black_pixels+=1
        print(black_pixels)
black_pixels/(w*h)
```

[image]

EDIT

I've googled around and managed a couple things. First, I have an efficient calculator of black pixels. Second I have a beginning calculator of cell growth regions. Would anyone know how to calculate the enclosed yellow boundaries below or have a different solution entirely?

```
img = Image.open("Images/24Hour/HB15_2.jpg")
img = img.convert('L')
img = np.asarray(img)
img = 1 * (img < 130) * (img > 90)
m,n = img.shape
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your cell growth is in non continuous shapes, we can't use shape detectors. So another option could be to do blob detection on the cells and then find the area to obtain a quantitative number. To detect the blobs, we first turn the image into grayscale and use [Canny edge detection](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html) which helps us to isolate the cell growth.

[image]

Next we can grab all the contours and find the area of each contour using `cv2.contourArea()`. We add each individual contour area to obtain the total area. It's a simple approach and isn't perfect but it grabs most of the blobs.

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy

def grab_contours(cnts):
    # OpenCV v2.4, v4-official
    if len(cnts) == 2:
        return cnts[0]
    # OpenCV v3
    elif len(cnts) == 3:
        return cnts[1]

image = cv2.imread("test.png")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 120, 255, 1)
cv2.imshow("canny", edged)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = grab_contours(cnts)

contour_image = edged.copy()
area = 0

for c in cnts:
    area += cv2.contourArea(c) 
    cv2.drawContours(contour_image,[c], 0, (100,5,10), 3)

print(area)
cv2.putText(contour_image, str(area), (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (100,255,100), 2)
cv2.imshow("area", contour_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to make all yellow into white and all purple into black. Then get the mean of the image and multiply by the width and by the height. That will compute the number of pixels that were yellow (i.e., the area). Perhaps you should save your image as grayscale or binary rather than colorizing it. As an example, here is a way using ImageMagick. But you likely can do the same with Python Wand, or OpenCV or scipy (skimage).

Note that I have download your image and cropped it to remove the other markings. So you will need to use your full image.

[image]

```
convert img_sub.png -alpha off -fuzz 10% -fill black -opaque "rgb(68,1,84)" -fill white +opaque black +write binary.png -format "%[fx:mean*w*h]\n" info:

58464
```

Here is the binary image that was save.

[image]